# Why can't I get the HTML video tag to align top?

Tags: css, html, video, alignment, html-table

My goal is to have the video take up the top 90% of a 1080p screen leaving the bottom 10% to be used by text.

No matter what I try the video never seems to fit or align.

Is there a trick to making this work with the html video tag?

```
 <table style="width:1080px;height:100%;background-color:#888">
  <tr valign="top">
    <td width="1080px" height="90%" valign="top">
<video width="1080px" height="100%" src="video.mp4" autoplay loop></video>
    </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>TEXT</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/1u1xc1sL/

[image]

Comment: Can you make a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure that has absolutely nothing to do in a `<table>`...

Comment: You could use the `vh` unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need remove `td` `height` and `video` `height`. See example in full page mode.

```css
body {width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden; margin:0; background-color:black;}
 html {width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden; }
```

```html
<html>

<body>
    <table style="width:1080px;height:100%;background-color:#888">
        <tr valign="top">
            <td width="1080px" valign="top" align="left">
                <video width="1080px" src="http://henriksjokvist.net/examples/html5-video/video.ogg" autoplay loop></video>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>TEXT</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

**USE CSS:**

```css
video {
  //how far from top
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<video style="background-color: black;" width="1080px" height="100%" src="video.mp4" autoplay loop>Your bowser dooes not support the video tag</video>
```

Answer (score 2):

Edited Answer: Your video container has a proportion that doesn't fit the video proportion itself: Your rule makes it 1074 x 1080, but it's height has to be less. This inline style won't work: `width="1080px" height="100%"` - it causes a grey area to be on top of the video area...

And when you force the table to be 100% height, its rows (and their `td`s)  will be stretched to fit that heigth. Remove that: https://jsfiddle.net/j2axmgdq/1/

Comment: true but it matters more that it is aligned to the top.